AWS load balancer nginx not found 404 (nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)
So I have an ec2 instance that I am able to access through its public ip address (I want to put out that the webpage is not secure when I do utilize the public ip). However when I put the instance behind an application load balancer and try to access the DNS name of the load balancer I am met with a "404 not found nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)" page. <-- I want to emphasize that the webpage is also not secure when I try ti pull up the DNS name of the LB Trying to access Load balancer DNS name. 
I have tried to restart the nginx server but that hasn't worked. I have also tried to edit /etc/nginx/sites-available directory but I'm not sure if should add another "server" section? I have also tried to add the load balancer DNS name to the first server section pictured here --> /etc/nginx/sites-available  (after server_name)...I then restarted the nginx server but still no luck. Has anyone ever experienced this before? Any help would be appreciated
